# Clear tapestry t:alerts messages

Tags: tapestry, alerts

I use alertManager.success to output t:alerts messages after the use press the Save button. If the user press the Save button multiple times, I would get multiple t:alerts messages displayed. How do I clear the previous t:alerts messages so that only 1 message is displayed?

Here is my tml file

```
<div class="center">
<t:alerts/>
</div>                      
<t:zone t:id="detailZone" id="detailZone" >
      <t:core.usermgmt.UserDetailComp t:id="detail"  mode="actionMode" previewUser="selectedUser" function="showFunctions"/>
</t:zone>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@SessionState(create = false)
private AlertStorage storage;

void onSomeEvent() {
    if (storage != null) {
        storage.dismissAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I have tried but it is still not working. Here is my code     if (storage != null) { storage.dismissAll(); }   alertManager.success("Test");

Comment: What event are you using? I'd probably use "prepareForSubmit". http://jumpstart.doublenegative.com.au/jumpstart/examples/navigation/whatiscalledandwhen

Comment: I put my alertManager.success("Test") in onSuccessFromForm in response to user pressing the Save button. I tried your suggestion and put the storage.dismissAll in onPrepareForSubmit but it is still not working.

Comment: I think you need to put the <t:alerts /> component inside your <t:zone />

Comment: If I put the <t:alerts/> component inside <t:zone/>, when the user press the save button, I get a red error message on the top left corner of the screen. The error message is "Communication with the server failed:TypeError:"null" is null or not an object". However, there is no error in the logs.

Comment: Are you returning detailZone.getBody() from your onSuccess() event?

Comment: I am not returning detailZone.getBody(). I use componentResources.triggerEvent("display", null, null); in my UserDetailComp. It goes back to the main page and calls the function void onDisplayFromDetail(). Inside this function, I call/refreshes the zone UserDetailComp using    if (request.isXHR()) {
   ajaxResponseRenderer.addRender(detailZone);
  }